# How do I access session properties in ember-simple-auth?

Tags: javascript, authentication, ember.js

I'm using a custom Facebook authenticator, very similar to the one given in the ember-simple-auth [example](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/7-facebook-auth.html#L91). I inject the properties `accountID` and `accessToken` into the session here:

```
if (fbResponse.status === 'connected') {
  console.log("AccountID: " + fbResponse.authResponse.userID);
  Ember.run(function() {
  resolve({
     accessToken: fbResponse.authResponse.accessToken,
     accountID: fbResponse.authResponse.userID
  });
});
```

If I read the [docs](http://ember-simple-auth.simplabs.com/api.html#Ember-SimpleAuth-Session) correctly, I should be able to access `accountID` using `session.accountID` in any controller. But, the only way I can find this is via `session.store._lastData.accountID`, which is probably not the right way to do it.

More specifically, in a controller, I have an action:

```
createRental: function() {
      var session = this.get('session');
      console.log(session.accountID); // undefined
      console.log(session.store._lastData.accountID); // '123456'
```

Does anyone with experience using ember-simple-auth know what the issue is? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `get`:

```
this.get('session.accountID')
```

or

```
var session = this.get('session');
session.get('accountID')
```

Comment: what about in a model? I want to access the user object I have attached to the session in a computed property of a protected resource.

Comment: The session is not available in models. You can probably manually inject it with Ember's dependency injection API (http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/#toc_dependency-injection-with-code-register-inject-code) in a custom initializer though.

Comment: Doesn't work for me in the console, using the `$E` object provided by Ember Inspector. `$E.get('session.isAuthenticated')` works, for example, but I can't reach anything inside `$E.session.store._lastData.secure` using the method in this answer. Similar results using a template; `..._lastData.secure.foo` is defined but not `session.foo`.

Comment: You should never access the store through the session. In templates use `session.secure.foo`.